# Ruby Acronym Creator from string

Tags: ruby, loops, acronym

I'm creating a function that takes a string and creates an acronym but am running into errors.
When I input `"Complementary metal-oxide semiconductor"` I get `"CS"` in return when expecting `"CMOS"`. Any suggestions why this might happen? I pass it plenty of other strings and it works, just doesn't work in this case.

```
class Acronym

    def self.abbreviate(phrase)
        letters = phrase.split("")
        acronym = []
        letters.each do |letter|
            previous = letters.index(letter) - 1
            if previous == -1
                acronym.push(letter)
            elsif letters[previous] == " " || letters[previous] == "-"
                acronym.push(letter)
            end
        end
        acronym.join("").upcase
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `index()` returns the *first* occurrence of the given letter. So, two problems:

1. The 'm' in 'metal' is not the first occurrence of 'm' in the string. It appears in the word 'complementary'. Thus, whenever it sees an 'm' in the string, previous will always be 'o' and thus not trigger a `push()`.
2. Anytime the first letter in your string recurs (regardless of position), it will trigger your first condition. You can see the effect if you change the initial 'C' to 'c' in your test string. The result will be `CSCC` because there are two 'c's in 'semiconductor'.

As an alternative, here is an option that uses regex:

```rb
def self.abbreviate(phrase)
  phrase.gsub('-', ' ')
        .scan(/(\A\w|(?<=\s)\w)/)
        .flatten
        .join.upcase
end
```

Step by step:

1. Borrowing the `.gsub` from @DollarChills to turn the '-' into a space.
2. `scan()` returns an array of all matches. The regex matches the first word in the string and any word that is preceded by a space.
3. The result of the `scan` is actually an array of arrays, so flatten unnests them.
4. Combine into a string and upcase

Comment: `join('') == join`

Comment: Nifty, thanks; never noticed that. I’ll edit the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 5):

Simplifies to

```
def acronym(str)
  str.split(/ |-/).map(&:first).join.upcase
end
```

The above depends on the Rails activesupport library. Here's a Ruby-only variation:

```
str.split(/ |-/).map { |s| s[0] }.join.upcase
```

Comment: Just note that ``String::first()`` is part of  ActiveSupport Core Extensions (aka a Rails thing). If you're using in a plain Ruby app you just need to install the ``activesupport`` gem and require ``activesupport/core_ext/string`.

Comment: @rmlockerd: This code is using `String#first`, not `String::first`. Otherwise, your point still stands.

Comment: Oops, yes, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [gsub](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) to ignore the hyphen.

```
<%= ('Complementary metal-oxide semiconductor').gsub('-', ' ') %>
```

Returns: Complementary metaloxide semiconductor

Comment: `tr('-', ' ')` is a good replacement for that use of gsub.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in `previous = letters.index(letter) - 1`

see if you can spot it:

```rb
arr = [:a, :b, :c, :a]
previous_indexes = arr.map { |n| arr.index(n) - 1 }
you_are_expecting = [-1, 0, 1, 2]

previous_indexes == you_are_expecting
# => false

arr.index(:a) # => 0
arr.index(:b) # => 1
arr.index(:c) # => 2
arr.index(:a) # => 0
```

To get indexes with iterating, use `with_index`:

```rb
arr = %i[a b c a]
arr.map.with_index { |x, i| [x, i] }
# => [[:a, 0], [:b, 1], [:c, 2], [:a, 3]]
```

If you make that fix, your code does what you intended.

A suggestion though: you can often avoid dealing with the details of array indexes. Take a look at how [@Mori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62867865/234593) works by operating at a higher level.